# Weighted-Jacobi method

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Suppose matrix $A$ is symmetric and positive definite. I'm studying the Weighted-Jacobi iteration method, but I don't know what value of weight $\omega$ I should pick. Most of the literature say that $\omega$ is usually chosen to be $\frac{2}{3}$. Why $\frac{2}{3}$, is there any proof on that?

Comment: A useful search term for you will be "relaxation parameter" for iterative methods.  The Wikipedia article [has a discussion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Successive_over-relaxation) of simple cases where the optimal relaxation parameter can be analytically determined.

Comment: Have you experimented with your favorite matrix and different values of $\omega$? Do you have any evidence to suggest that $\omega = \frac{2}{3}$ is anywhere near the optimal value?

Answer (score 0):

Look at https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-086-mathematical-methods-for-engineers-ii-spring-2006/readings/am62.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwj9lduUoczhAhWBq54KHRaFDYgQFjABegQIBBAB&usg=AOvVaw172VJgpocqF3bOp7BEz8LP pages 4-5 have the explanation. Basically, it says that 2/3 is the optimal value for a system with a standard discrete Laplacian matrix